# How to build a edit form with the lithium framework

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks, lithium

I'm trying to write a edit form with the lithium framework (0.10). I'm using MySQL as the DBMS. The controller looks like this:

```
public function edit() {
    $success = false;

    $data = Posts::find(42);

    return compact('data');
}
```

The view file:

```
<?=$this->form->create(); ?>
    <?=$this->form->field('title');?>
    <?=$this->form->field('body', array('type' => 'textarea'));?>
    <?=$this->form->submit('Add Post'); ?>
<?=$this->form->end(); ?>

<?php if ($success): ?>
    <p style="color: red;">Post Successfully Saved</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

When calling the site a get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type lithium\data\entity\Record as array in /var/www/web/frameworks/lithium-0.10/app/resources/tmp/cache/templates/template_views_posts_edit.html_483_1313415231_358.php on line 2
```

What am I doing wrong? Whats the right way to build a edit form in lithium? Unfortunately, there is no information on this in the [official lithium docs](http://li3.me/docs/manual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass the data to form. So that will become

```
<?=$this->form->create($data); ?>
```

You can look http://li3.me/docs/manual/quickstart which I have been playing some months back. Hope this will work with the latest also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just one more question, what is the method I have to use to save the changed data? ATM I've got `if($this->request->data) {
   $post = Posts::update($this->request->data);
   $success = $post->save();
  }`

Comment: As you can see in http://dev.lithify.me/forks/harikt/lithium_blog, first I get the object `$user = User::find($this->request->id);` if not redirect else do the save on it via `$user->save($this->request->data)` .